# Using ADF, Copy Activity I have created a file with custom filename . How can I create an empty .fin file along with this in the same name?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory, Copy Activity.
My Source is Stored Procedure.
I am creating a file with custom filename using expression builder. This is a file with tab extension.
Till this part I have implemented.
I need to create an empty .FIN file also with the same filename How can I achieve this? Can I use the same Copy Activity for this?

Comment: What is the .FIN file for? Is it a completely empty text file?

Comment: ' Can I use the same Copy Activity for this?' - AFAIK, you need to use another copy activity for it.

Comment: @Vipina K, .FIN file format is not supported in ADF.

Comment: Yes. This .FIN file is completely empty

Comment: @Vipina K, As per this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs), .FIN file format is not supported in ADF.